# ZipEntry getEntry() always returns null

Tags: java, file-io, zip

I have a zip file that I would like to extract a file from and right now, I have this code that is supposed to send that file through a Spring controller.

```
    //This code is in a Spring Controller to send the screenshot.
    ZipFile file = new ZipFile("path/to/zipFile.zip");
    try(InputStream is = searchImage(screenshotFileName, file)){
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is,servletOutputStream);
    }catch (IOException e){
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }


private InputStream searchImage(String screenshotFileName, ZipFile file) throws IOException{
    ZipEntry entry = file.getEntry(screenshotFileName);
    if(entry != null){
        return file.getInputStream(entry);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem that I am running into, is that every time this code runs, the `InputStream` is being returned as null meaning that the `getEntry` method isn't finding the screenshot. I looked at the zip file and I know for a fact that the screenshot file exists in the zipped file. Am I going about this wrong? The zip file that I am looking in does have a lot of sub directories, do I need to search through those to find the screenshot?

Comment: You have to provide the full path, not just the name, and the path has to agree exactly with what is in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem which I also think applies to you. It's because the internal path delimiters can be either `/` or `\` so you either need to know how it was written into the ZIP originally or check for both types when reading with `getEntry()`! I see that you too are mixing the delimiters in your problem and solution:

```
new ZipFile("path/to/zipFile.zip")
"C:\\" + screenshotFileName
```

so this is probably the issue. This took me 4 hours to realize so I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract a single file from a zip file in a different way using `FileSystem`. You can extract a single file by using this code

```
File outputFile = new File("C:\\" + screenshotFileName);
Path zipFile = Paths.get("\\path\\to\\Zip.zip");
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFile,null);
Path source = fileSystem.getPath(screenshotPath);
Files.copy(source, outputFile.toPath());
```

Now the input stream can easily be created because the file from within the zip is not located at `C:\screenshotFileName`. No need to use `ZipEntry` class for this problem.

Comment: This didn't solve my bug, but I think I found the real solution. You might need to use the Windows backslash delimiter "\" consistent with how you created the ZIP, not the Unix forward-slash "/" to obtain the entry from the ZIP.